# Error in R: Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[10,10] = 0

Tags: r, plm

I want to use `pgmm` function in the package `plm` to produce `GMM` estimate on a cross-section country data including 4 countries and 20 time periods (quarterly 5 years)

Here is my code:

```
formula = log(y2) ~ lag(log(y2),1) + lag(log(y2),2) + EU_IM + 
          lag(EU_IM, 1) + lag(EU_IM, 2) + Non_EU_IM + 
          lag(Non_EU_IM, 1) + lag(Non_EU_IM, 2) + log(GDP)
erg.gmm2 = pgmm(formula, data = df, effect = "individual", model ="onestep", 
                gmm.inst =~log(y2), lag.gmm = list(c(2,3)) )
```

I get the following error:

```
#Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[10,10] = 0
```

Any suggestions how I can solve the problem or why this error occurs?

Comment: Is it possible to re-create this problem with an example dataset.